# How to create pyspark schema to read json with array of different types?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to create a schema to read a complex json file, where one of the structfields are of the type array(array(integer, integer), double), ie.

```
"prediction_probability":[[0,0],0.0788,[1,0],0.0015]
```

How do I specify the field. It should be something along
`StructField(name="prediction_probability", dataType=ArrayType(??), nullable=True)`
Hope someone has a good suggestion, TIA

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to define `StructType`, containing fields of all possible types you expect in your array (int_member, string_member, array_member, etc) and set this struct as type of your array. In each element of array you then set only one member - the one with right type.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. The array in question can be imported as array(stringtype()), which can then be manipulated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).